# Java Nashorn invokeFunction attributes object

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I am trying to find a way to get the attributes passed to a javascript function called by the Nashorn ScriptEngine.

So for example I am calling

```
invocable.invokeFunction(execFn, newArgs);
```

I want to be able to get the arguments list as an array from inside the JS function like regular javascript "arguments" object.. is there anyway for that?

Comment: Have you checked to see what the value is of the `arguments` object in the invoked function?

Comment: Yes.. it has no value.. arguments, args, argument, arg .. trying to read them throws an exception

Comment: @pointy looks like I wrote it wrong.. it works..